# Count nodes with and without subsequent child nodes

Tags: c#, treeview

I am trying to count number of tree nodes with (A) and without subsequent child nodes (B). For example the image below should return 2/1.

[image: img]

I tried to play around with `TreeView` methods but cant figure out how to work with deeper level nodes.

```
private void tvResources_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    int a=0,b=0;          
    foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Nodes)               
    {              
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Contains(node))
            a += 1;
        else
            b += 1;
    }           
    e.Node.Text += @" - " + a+"/"+b;
}
```

This can probably be done with some recursive function, but is there any easier solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you need just the current node (before expanding), you could just use the `foreach` loop to check the number of nodes for each direct child and that will give you the answer directly.

```
private void tvResources_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    CalculateAB( e.Node );
}

private void CalculateAB( TreeNode node )
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    foreach ( TreeNode child in node.Nodes )
    {
        if ( child.Nodes.Count() > 0 )
        {
            a++;
        } 
        else
        {
            b++;
        }
    }
    node.Text += @" - " + a + "/" + b;
}
```

You can then use recursion if you want to calculate the values for the whole `TreeView` at once. You can use depth-first search and calculate the `a/b` values of all nodes you encounter using the `CalculateAB` method.

```
private void CalculateForTree( TreeNode root )
{
    foreach ( var child in root.Nodes )
    {
        CalculateForTree( child );
    }
    CalcualteAB( root );    
}
```

Comment: Yearly unclosed answer review - @MrOleg , if this heped, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is closed.